# SIP ( Asterisk ) CoS solutions with no VLAN's?

Tags: networking, vlan, asterisk, sip, junos

I have a Asterisk box actually two running pure asterisk. No GUI i.e. FreePBX, TL etc. The asterisk box is connected to a an EX4200 VC Stack, the EX4200's then connect to our headquarters via a Qwest Metro Optical Ethernet line or QMOE. All it is for those not familiar with it is a very expensive site 2 site VPN. It terminates to our EX2200 PoE's switches in HQ.

Now the problem is that QMOE will not recognize any VLAN,DSCP tags. This line will be upgraded but unfortunately in our datacenter they will have to change the drop to fibre increasing the price and surpassing our budget for this year.

My question is this, I would like to get as much QoS as possible. Not having a MPLS line to HQ is a huge handicap but, can I do anything to make sure that SIP is receiving the most stable bandwidth ?

My thoughts have been :

1) ACL / Firewall statements stating anything from 10.10.0.35/32 gets the "expedited forwarding"

2) Local switch VLAN's, meaning just a VLAN local to the EX4200.

3) Or both let me explain :

I setup a port based VLAN 100 on the upstream EX4200's, those ports are connected to the LAN of the PBX's. Asterisk is passing or setup for VLAN 100. Now I tell the EX4200 that VLAN 100 is the "Voice VLAN" this should isolate it from server traffic.  When data is sent to HQ, the EX2200's see that it coming from IP 10.10.0.35 and place it in VLAN 100 assigning it "Expedited Forwarding".

A few questions on this, 
Am not sure if the EX2200's can do VLAN placement, I am running firmware 10.4r5. If they cannot can I just do a simple statement on both ends saying anything for the PBX's IP or MAC 
gets "Expedited Forwarding" ? Asterisk / SIP is so sensitive to network configurations I need to make this as clean cut as possible. I do not need the IP-Phones to be on a different subnet. All I really want is anything coming and going from/to 10.10.0.35 to receive priority. If there are any JunOS experts do you think you could show me a simple statement to get me going in the correct direction ?

Comment: Are you actually having a problem yet? You could place a firewall filter on the L3 interfaces and have them classify traffic into these QoS classes for you and then just accept all other traffic. The QMOE line should be giving you L2 from site to site so it shouldn't really affect QoS I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should think this would do:

```
set firewall family inet filter test term 1 from source-address 10.10.0.35/32
set firewall family inet filter test term 1 then loss-priority high
set firewall family inet filter test term 1 then forwarding-class expedited-forwarding
set firewall family inet filter test term 2 then accept
```

Then on the interface:

```
set interfaces vlan unit 991 family inet filter input test
```

On the other end:

```
set firewall family inet filter test term 1 from destination-address 10.10.0.35/32
set firewall family inet filter test term 1 then loss-priority high
set firewall family inet filter test term 1 then forwarding-class expedited-forwarding
set firewall family inet filter test term 2 then accept
```

Then on the other end you'd set the filter on that VLAN interface as well.

Play around with it and see if that works for you.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the help. I will test with this, this weekend.